# excludedActivityTypes doesn't work in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on my image iOS application and I just added an image share button and I wanted some features of Share types to be excluded but when I run in the simulator, all the features are there.

Here is my code...

```
let image = UIImage("b3")
let imageToShare = [image!]
let shareImage =  UIActivityViewController (activity items:imageToShare,application Activities:nil)
shareImage.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present (shareImage,animated:true,completion:nil)
shareImage.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print,UIActivityType. copyToPasteboard]
```

How to exclude them ?
please provide any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of `excludedActivityTypes` on `UIActivityViewController`

Like this:

```
shareImage.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print,UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard]
self.present (shareImage,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

Comment: @Haileapp - happy to hear

Answer (score 2):

You are presenting your activity view controller before setting excludedActivityTypes. Replace your code with below code:

```
let image = UIImage("b3")
let imageToShare = [image!]
let shareImage = UIActivityViewController (activity items:imageToShare,application Activities:nil)
shareImage.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
shareImage.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard]
self.present (shareImage, animated:true, completion:nil)
```